# Como ordenar uma lista pela hora atual e os próximos registros datados

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho a seguinte tabela contendo a programação do dia da semana "domingo" de uma rádio:

(id,programa,descricao,hora_ini,hora_fim,link)

Quero obter os 3 primeiros programas usando como referência a hora atual.

Comment: Você está utilizando a coluna com o tipo `TIME`?

Comment: @AtilaCardoso: Qual é o gerenciador de banco de dados? // Como estão declaradas as colunas hora_ini e hora_fim? // Você quer uma consulta SQL ou tratar diretamente no código PHP?

Comment: Sim. uso a coluna tipo time; O gerenciador é o mySql.  Prefiro uma consulta mas se não for possível o tratamento com o php será uma saída também

Comment: bem vindo, leia esse post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485

Comment: Obrigado Leo Caracciolo. Na próxima vou seguir as recomendações.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avalise se o seguinte código te atende.

```
-- código #1
SELECT id, programa, descricao, hora_ini, hora_fim, link
  from tbProgramacao
  where id >= (SELECT id
                 from tbProgramacao
                 where hora_ini <= curtime()
                 order by hora_ini desc
                 limit 1)
  order by hora_ini asc
  limit 3;
```

Para obter a programação que está no ar, você pode caminhar na tabela pela ordem inversa (do último para o primeiro), comparando com a hora corrente. Obtido o id da programação em andamento, basta então obter os 3.

Há algum tempo que não programo para MySQL; por favor teste o código com cuidado.

Na cláusula WHERE do SELECT principal (o externo), no lugar de id pode-se utilizar hora_ini:

```
where hora_ini >= (SELECT hora_ini
```

Comment: Muito obrigado. Salvou os dias.